# Removing Commented Lines in PHP

Tags: php

I've been doing some work with different PHP scripts and had a quick question.  In quite a few of them there are commented out lines like these:

```
/*
  $a = 1; $b = 2; $x = 1;

  $y = $a * $x + $b;

  if ( $y < 5 )
*/
```

Are these lines safe to delete if they are commented out?  What's the point of having code in files that's just commented out?

Comment: Why do you ask us? I didn't commented it out, so you should ask your coworkers, who did it :D

Comment: Yeah, you can delete them if you know you don't need them. Comments are really *comments* that a programmer will write to remind himself what he was doing. (or had been, anyway)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's the point of having code in files that's just commented out?

Nothing. Some developers do it for backlogging old code. This is bad practice, as one should use source control (such as SVN or GIT) instead, and all the history will be in there **along** with commit messages why it was commented out/replaced.

They're definitely safe to delete, but you might want to ask the developer *why* they commented them out instead of simply removing them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, those lines can safely be removed. You should be careful, however, that the code isn't still relevant; it may have been left there for a reason by another developer.

Comments are often used as a tool to "disable" a section of code without removing it entirely, so that if you need the code later you can simply uncomment it to reinstate it.

It's bad practice to leave commented code in the long term, however (this is what version control is for).

Answer (score 0):

The previous author may have done some tests in their code and then commented them out for future testing. There could be any number of reasons.

Yes, its completely safe to delete those comments if they bother you.

Comment: Great, thanks for clarifying that!  I was just making sure that I wasn't missing something important and wanted to get that confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

You are the only one who really knows whether the lines can be safely removed.

Basically, yes - if your application works as intended, by all means remove them.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting a comment block such as the above will have no impact on the output of the code.

People often comment out code rather than delete it if they wish to refer back to it later. A better option is to use source control and you can then look back at the previous code and see why and when it was removed.

Answer (score 0):

It is safe to have these removed. Actually there is no use of having such comments if you are using a version control system. This kind of comment usually occurs when people are not using a versioning system and comment code out to try something and want to keep the old code, just in case. If you are using a version control system you can always get an old version of the code back, so by all means remove these comments. If you are not using a version control system, you really should.

Answer (score 0):

Don't touch until you know why the code commented. Ask the developer who developed this code or go through the code and understand first if do you need those lines or not.